# using multiprocessing when running on a function

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am trying to delete some files from a csv,

this is what it looks like

```
print(len(file))
for index, item in enumerate(file['filenames']):
   try:
       Image.open(os.path.join(image_file_path,item.split('/')[-1]))
   except Exception as e:
       file.drop(index, inplace = True)
       print(index)
       pass
```

But this is really,really slow.

So i tried this method.

```
file = pd.read_csv('/home/data/dory_train/v1/ryan_01.csv', names = ['filepath', 'text'])

def multi_csv(csv_file):
   for index, value in enumerate(file['filepath']):  
      try:  
         Image.open(value)
      except Exception as e:
         file.drop(file.index[index], inplace = True)
         file.to_csv('/home/ryan/coco/loopandtest.csv', header = False, index  = False)
      print(index)

def mp_handler():
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(12)
    p.map(multi_csv, file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp_handler()
```

But even this does not seem to help much , My first worry is, have i implemented this multiprocessing correcly? and is there something i can do to speed this up?

Info: My CPU has 12 cores, the csv has 2900000 rows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll recommend you to use threads instead of multiprocess and set the amount of thread based on your CPU cores quantity. Another thing is the race condition, you're trying to use the same resource concurrently so i recommend you to use Lock to read the file or create a thread that reads from file and output into a Queue and consume the queue from other threads. Queues on python are synchronised and will help you to avoid race condition on file resources.

Comment: Hmmm, Okay , let me check this out.